# Symlink as WorkingDirectory in systemd service

Tags: systemd, symlink, services

I have a service with `WorkingDirectory=/srv/ctr/current` which is a symlink.

It seems the service doesn't pick up changes in the symlink when restarted. The error log reports `/srv/ctr/releases/69` as the location but the `/srv/ctr/current` points to `/srv/ctr/releases/72`. Is there any way I can get systemd to pick up on the new directory change?

Comment: Have you tried `systemctl daemon-reload`? Might trigger a re-read of the symlink.

Comment: @morloch yes I tried that. The service which I'm running is [resque](https://github.com/resque/resque). I'm wondering if the path is somehow stored in the job itself.

Comment: Try adding `ExecStartPre=/bin/pwd -P` to your service, reload/restart the service and check the logs.  At least then you'll know if it's systemd or resque...

Comment: @morloch that worked and now somehow it's finding the right directory.

Comment: I had the same issue. SystemD will resolve the SymLink to the actual path and use that. I've not found a way to disable this behavior. I've now simply moved my stuff to the symlink target and create a new link in the other direction...

Answer (score 2):

Possibly try adding:

`Environment = PWD=/srv/ctr/current`

(BTW, really happy to see someone else using `/srv/*` for their services.)

Comment: Old question, but wanted to say that this worked for me on Centos 8.1's systemd while @morloch's comment did not.

Answer (score 0):

modify your systemd unit file to be as follows:

- WorkingDirectory=/srv/ctr/
- ExecStart=/bin/start current or ExecStart= cd current && /bin/start